# Why is "I need help choosing the right laptop model" off topic in Hardware recommendations stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

My post was deleted stating that it was off topic without adequate details.
I have clearly mentioned my purpose, clearly defined the specifications of each of the three laptop models. I even got a decisive answer from a user.

But still one of the admins deleted my post stating that it is off topic and lacks detail i.e., cannot be given a decisive answer.

I have included the screen shots below. Kindly explain why this is off topic and why this can't be answered with the details given.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In short, I closed your question because there aren't sufficient details in it to narrow down the choice to any one of your three proposed options. The proposed usage you've given is:

> Extensive browsing... watching videos... reading PDF documents... MS Office

That's pretty light work for any modern computer, and any of the three you've proposed would be more than capable of handling that; what you want it for is nothing out of the ordinary.

Without more details on any special workloads you want it to handle, there's simply nothing to go on to narrow down the selection, hence my closure as "insufficient detail".